# Fail to load files using karma-jasmine for ui-router testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I am trying to use karma/jasmine for unit test, but it fails when I run `karma start`. Here are my codes:

---

`app.js`

```
angular
.module('app', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'oc.lazyLoad'
])
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$ocLazyLoad', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $ocLazyLoad) {
    $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/app.directive.js']);
}]);
```

---

`app.spec.js`

```
describe("test", function() {
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    }));
    // some other codes
});
```

It shows `404: /app/app.directive.js`. So what is the reason?

---

Edit

Tree of my project is like this.

```
myproject
  src
    app
      app.js
      app.directive.js
  tests
    app.spec.js
  karma.conf.js
```

I thought it might be the fault of my directory structure, so i tried to run `karma start` under `myproject` and `src`, but it still errors.

Comment: do you have the file `app/app.directive.js`?

Comment: @faboolous of course I have